# How to switch to main window

Tags: python, lightweight-charts

```
import pandas as pd
from lightweight_charts import Chart

# ascii symbols
FULLSCREEN = '■'
CLOSE = '×'


def on_max(target_chart):
    button = target_chart.topbar['max']
    if button.value == CLOSE:
        [c.resize(0.5, 0.5) for c in charts]
        button.set(FULLSCREEN)
    else:
        for chart in charts:
            width, height = (1, 1) if chart == target_chart else (0, 0)
            chart.resize(width, height)
        button.set(CLOSE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_chart = Chart(inner_width=0.5, inner_height=0.5)
    charts = [
        main_chart,
        main_chart.create_subchart(position='top', width=0.5, height=0.5),
        main_chart.create_subchart(position='left', width=0.5, height=0.5),
        main_chart.create_subchart(position='right', width=0.5, height=0.5),
    ]

    df = pd.read_csv('examples/1_setting_data/ohlcv.csv')
    for i, c in enumerate(charts):
        chart_number = str(i+1)
        c.watermark(chart_number)
        c.topbar.textbox('number', chart_number)
        c.topbar.button('max', FULLSCREEN, False, align='right', func=on_max)
        c.set(df)

    charts[0].show(block=True)
```

When i start the app, 4 charts appear and each one has a full screen button. I try to have only one chart appear when opening the app and the other 4 appear when pressing minimize